Neovim with mason cannot launch typescript-language-server
I'm a beginner nvim user (version v0.11.0-dev). I've got my config forked from kickstart.nvim and it works on my personal machine with EndeavourOS. On my work laptop, I've got Windows with WSL, on which I've installed nvim with the same config. I cannot get typescript LSP to work though. :LspLog says this (the same is thrown when I try to run typescript-language-server manually from ~/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin:
[ERROR][2024-11-19 15:33:21] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:759    "rpc"   "/home/<redacted>/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/typescript-language-server"   "stderr"    "internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/<redacted>/.local/share/nvim/mason/typescript-language-server/lib/cli.mjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Looks like it searches a non-existent directory, because
ls -la ~/.local/share/nvim/mason/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 <redacted> <redacted> 4096 Nov 18 15:18 .
drwx------ 6 <redacted> <redacted> 4096 Nov 19 11:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 <redacted> <redacted> 4096 Nov 19 11:07 bin
drwxr-xr-x 5 <redacted> <redacted> 4096 Nov 19 11:07 packages
drwxr-xr-x 3 <redacted> <redacted> 4096 Nov 18 15:18 registries
drwxr-xr-x 3 <redacted> <redacted> 4096 Nov 18 15:18 share
drwxr-xr-x 2 <redacted> <redacted> 4096 Nov 19 11:07 staging

and typescript-language-server exists in packages and bin. I'm not sure what went wrong here.
:checkhealth mason does not indicate any errors (apart from warnings about language executables that I don't have)

Can you verify that your node.js and npm is correctly installed? Especially if with :checkhealth mason you see any warnings regarding node.js installation
